# Comparing a list of objects

Tags: java

I have a program that represents a deck of cards using an `ArrayList` and I want to compare two decks to see if they are equal (have the same size, same cards, and in the same order). I know you can do list1.equals(list2) for a type like `int` and it will return true if both are: (1,2,3) for example. When I try to do that with a list of `Card` objects it returns false . My code to create the deck is:

```
public DeckofCards(){
    for (Suits s : Suits.values()) {
        for(Values v : Values.values()){
            card = new Card(v,s);
            deck.add(card);
        }  
    }
}
```

And I also have a method: `deckToList` which just returns `deck`. So if I do:

```
DeckofCards dc = new DeckofCards();
DeckofCards dc2 = new DeckofCards();
List<Card> l1 = dc.deckToList();
List<Card> l2 = dc2.deckToList();

l1.equals(l2);
```

That returns false even though if I print out both l1 and l2 they have the same cards in the same order since I didn't manipulate the decks. Now if I set both `l1` and `l2` to `dc` then it returns true. Since I am using an `Object` does the `equals` method just look at the address and not the values? I'm not really sure what is going on or how to correctly compare the two.

Comment: How are you even calling `compareTo` on your `List`?  The [`List` interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#method.summary) doesn't have the `compareTo` method.

Comment: Is your code compiled successfully?

Comment: Sorry I typed this by memory, I meant `equals()` not `compareTo()`

Answer (score 0):

According to implementation of `Abstract List's` `equals` methos the super class of `ArrayList` which can be found [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7u40-b43/java/util/AbstractList.java#512)

**You should override `equals` method of `Card` class**

Good implementation when talking about cards is check whether their values and colors are equal

Something like this might work

```
@Override
   public boolean equals(Object other){
       if(this == other) return true;

       if(other == null || (this.getClass() != other.getClass())){
           return false;
       }

       Card otherCard = (Card) other;
       return (this.value == otherCard.value) &&
              (this.color == otherCard.color);
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your card object dont implement a good equals

if you see the implementation of the equals on the ArrayList (actually AbstractList), you see that iterates on both list and try to the equals the elements.

Answer (score 0):

When you call the constructor `DeckofCards()`, it is creating both a new `List` and a new `Card` for every value - the clue is the keyword `new`.  This means that a new memory location is allocated for all of those objects.  So when you create two `DeckofCards` objects they each contain their own `List` object which contains 52 `Card` objects: 104 separate `Card` objects in total.

Unless a class overrides the `equals` method it will use the default provided by `Object`, which just compares memory locations.  Now, `List` does override `equals` and it does this by calling `equals` on each of the `Card` objects it contains, but since it does not override `equals` then the  default `Object` version will be called.  All the `Card`s are in different memory locations albeit some have the same value (in different `DeckOfCards` objects), therefore these `List` objects are not equal.

So the advice is override `equals`, Ziker's implementation looks fine. But in general, if you override `equals` don't forget to override `hashcode`, too, otherwise you will get terrible performance from Collections such as `HashSet` or `HashMap`.